# message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, nszombie

After more than one day reading questions and trying to apply answers, I must ask more help.

My ios6 app has a table view on the main screen. After selecting a cell, we access a view controller with a UINavigationBar which has a custom "Back" button calling this method :

```
- (IBAction)goback:(id)sender {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    if(self.presentingViewController) {
        NSLog(@"  Dismissing View Controller: %@.", self.presentingViewController);
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Usually, this method works well. It only crashes if we press the Back button very quickly, just after the loading of the content (using json and AFNetworking). 5 seconds later, the back button is working fine, but if we click it right after the loading, we get this error :

```
[28103:c07]   Dismissing View Controller:     <UITabBarController: 0x7578170>.
[28103:c07] *** -[CustomViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1257cf70
```

Obviously, it's a memory problem. That's why I tried to track "Zombies". Profiling my app, I get this report. It shows that there is too much release, but I can't tell which one is the culprit.

Does anyone know how to interpret this report ?

Is this line normal ?

```
84  0x10291ff0  Release 3   MyApp   __destroy_helper_block_
```

Please tell me if any further information is needed. I thank you for your help.

```
#   Address Event Type  RefCt   Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   0x10291ff0  Malloc  1   UIKit   -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:]
1   0x10291ff0  Retain  2   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
2   0x10291ff0  Retain  3   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
3   0x10291ff0  Retain  4   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
4   0x10291ff0  Retain  5   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
5   0x10291ff0  Retain  6   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
6   0x10291ff0  Retain  7   UIKit   -[UIStoryboardScene setSceneViewController:]
7   0x10291ff0  Retain  8   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
8   0x10291ff0  Release 7   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
9   0x10291ff0  Release 6   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
10  0x10291ff0  Release 5   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
11  0x10291ff0  Release 4   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
12  0x10291ff0  Release 3   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
13  0x10291ff0  Release 2   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
14  0x10291ff0  Retain  3   UIKit   -[UIStoryboardSegue initWithIdentifier:source:destination:]
15  0x10291ff0  Retain  4   UIKit   -[UIViewController setChildModalViewController:]
16  0x10291ff0  Retain  5   UIKit   -[UIApplication _addViewControllerForLockingStatusBarTintColor:]
17  0x10291ff0  Retain  6   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
18  0x10291ff0  Retain  7   UIKit   +[UIProxyObject addMappingFromIdentifier:toObject:forCoder:]
19  0x10291ff0  Retain  8   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
20  0x10291ff0  Retain  9   UIKit   +[UIProxyObject addMappingFromIdentifier:toObject:forCoder:]
21  0x10291ff0  Retain  10  UIKit   -[UIProxyObject initWithCoder:]
22  0x10291ff0  Retain  11  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
23  0x10291ff0  Retain  12  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
24  0x10291ff0  Retain  13  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
25  0x10291ff0  Retain  14  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
26  0x10291ff0  Retain  15  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
27  0x10291ff0  Retain  16  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
28  0x10291ff0  Retain  17  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
29  0x10291ff0  Retain  18  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
30  0x10291ff0  Retain  19  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
31  0x10291ff0  Retain  20  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
32  0x10291ff0  Retain  21  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
33  0x10291ff0  Retain  22  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
34  0x10291ff0  Retain  23  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
35  0x10291ff0  Retain  24  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
36  0x10291ff0  Retain  25  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
37  0x10291ff0  Retain  26  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
38  0x10291ff0  Retain  27  UIKit   -[UIProxyObject initWithCoder:]
39  0x10291ff0  Retain  28  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
40  0x10291ff0  Retain  29  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
41  0x10291ff0  Retain  30  UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
42  0x10291ff0  Retain  31  UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
43  0x10291ff0  Retain  32  UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
44  0x10291ff0  Retain  33  UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
45  0x10291ff0  Release 32  UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
46  0x10291ff0  Release 31  UIKit   +[UIProxyObject removeMappingsForCoder:]
47  0x10291ff0  Release 30  UIKit   +[UIProxyObject removeMappingsForCoder:]
48  0x10291ff0  Release 29  UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
49  0x10291ff0  Release 28  UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
50  0x10291ff0  Release 27  UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
51  0x10291ff0  Release 26  UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
52  0x10291ff0  Release 25  UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
53  0x10291ff0  Release 24  UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
54  0x10291ff0  Release 23  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
55  0x10291ff0  Release 22  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
56  0x10291ff0  Release 21  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
57  0x10291ff0  Release 20  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
58  0x10291ff0  Release 19  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
59  0x10291ff0  Release 18  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
60  0x10291ff0  Release 17  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
61  0x10291ff0  Release 16  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
62  0x10291ff0  Release 15  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
63  0x10291ff0  Release 14  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
64  0x10291ff0  Release 13  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
65  0x10291ff0  Release 12  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
66  0x10291ff0  Release 11  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
67  0x10291ff0  Release 10  UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
68  0x10291ff0  Release 9   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
69  0x10291ff0  Release 8   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
70  0x10291ff0  Release 7   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
71  0x10291ff0  Release 6   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
72  0x10291ff0  Release 5   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]
73  0x10291ff0  Retain  6   MyApp   -[SSPullToRefreshView initWithScrollView:delegate:]
74  0x10291ff0  Release 5   MyApp   -[SSPullToRefreshView initWithScrollView:delegate:]
75  0x10291ff0  Retain  6   UIKit   -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:]
76  0x10291ff0  Retain  7   libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib  _Block_object_assign
77  0x10291ff0  Retain  8   libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib  _Block_object_assign
78  0x10291ff0  Release 7   Foundation  __NSFireDelayedPerform
79  0x10291ff0  Release 6   UIKit   -[UIStoryboardSegue dealloc]
80  0x10291ff0  Release 5   Foundation  __NSFireDelayedPerform
81  0x10291ff0  Release 4   UIKit   -[UIStoryboardScene dealloc]
82  0x10291ff0  Retain  5   UIKit   __91-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:]_block_invoke_0238
83  0x10291ff0  Release 4   UIKit   __destroy_helper_block_250
84  0x10291ff0  Release 3   MyApp   __destroy_helper_block_
85  0x10291ff0  Release 2   UIKit   -[UIWindowController transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:removeFromView:]
86  0x10291ff0  Retain  3   UIKit   -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:]
87  0x10291ff0  Retain  4   UIKit   __91-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:]_block_invoke_0238
88  0x10291ff0  Retain  5   UIKit   -[UIViewController _didFinishDismissTransition]
89  0x10291ff0  Retain  6   UIKit   -[UIApplication _removeViewControllerForLockingStatusBarTintColor:]
90  0x10291ff0  Release 5   UIKit   -[UIApplication _removeViewControllerForLockingStatusBarTintColor:]
91  0x10291ff0  Release 4   UIKit   -[UIApplication _removeViewControllerForLockingStatusBarTintColor:]
92  0x10291ff0  Release 3   UIKit   -[UIViewController setChildModalViewController:]
93  0x10291ff0  Release 2   UIKit   -[UIViewController _didFinishDismissTransition]
94  0x10291ff0  Release 1   UIKit   -[UIWindowController transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:removeFromView:]
95  0x10291ff0  Release 0   UIKit   -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:]
96  0x10291ff0  Zombie  -1  UIKit   -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _delegateScrollViewAnimationEnded]
```

-- edit --

Here is how I use AFNetworking to retrieve data on each page of my app :

```
[[APIClient sharedClient] getPath:request
                            parameters:params
                               success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                   [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                                   [self.pullToRefreshView finishLoading];

                                   ... read data ...                                       

                               } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                   [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:error.localizedDescription];
                               }];
```

There is no will/didUnload methods, only this one:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [_pubnub unsubscribeFromChannel: self.pro.channel];
}
```

Comment: can you post some code from your custom view controller like dealloc and viewDidUnload:

Comment: Is your code executing "respondsToSelector"?  If so, can you show that snippet?  And, is there any asynchronous execution occurring with AFNetworking?  Are you using blocks anywhere?

Comment: *Had exactly the same problem.*

Comment: @nkongara if I remove everything from my dealloc method, the problem i still there. I have added the only method executed when the view disappear.

Comment: @jbbenni I can only find "respondsToSelector" in libraries I'm using, not in my own code. There is an asynchronous call with AFNetworking and the problem appear only if we leave the screen just after the reception of the response.

Comment: @rohan-patel Did you use AFNetworking like I do ? What are the common points between your code and mine ?

Comment: Add your own dealloc method to that viewController and add a breakpoint to it. From what we can see in your question, you are referencing `self` within that block which will cause it to be retained. It seems weird that your symptoms look as if it does not get retained over the course of that request to finish.

Comment: No. I did not use it. My issue is [here](https://gist.github.com/patelrohan/5153535).

Comment: @rohan-patel the code snippet in your link pushes a view controller with animation and then immediately releases it. That seems like an invitation to trouble.  I suspect the VC is being referenced until the annimation finishes, and your release is executed before that moment.  (You could test this theory by trying with NO animation.  And if you do wish to use animation, you could setup a completion block to release the VC when it is safe).

Comment: Ok. Will give it a try